# jooq and java 8 streams SQL generation

Tags: java, sql, java-8, java-stream, jooq

In below jooq snippet that I found from [online material](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-java-8/), there is a transition from "jooq ends here" to "stream starts"

Does this mean SQL query generation happens till fetch() ?
And later on afterwards stream() starts, everything is in memory inside java process

Or are java 8 streams like active record DSL and whole snippet is converted into SQL queries including stream() part ?

This is because I have seen examples where sortBy / groupingBy are being done inside streams in many online samples when they can be done in SQL as well

```
DSL.using(c)
   .select(
       COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,
       COLUMNS.TYPE_NAME
   )
   .from(COLUMNS)
   .orderBy(
       COLUMNS.TABLE_CATALOG,
       COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION
   )
   .fetch()  // jOOQ ends here
   .stream() // Streams start here
   .collect(groupingBy(
       r -> r.getValue(COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME),
       LinkedHashMap::new,
       mapping(
           r -> new Column(
               r.getValue(COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME),
               r.getValue(COLUMNS.TYPE_NAME)
           ),
           toList()
       )
   ))
   .forEach(
       (table, columns) -> {
            // Just emit a CREATE TABLE statement
            System.out.println(
                "CREATE TABLE " + table + " (");

            // Map each "Column" type into a String
            // containing the column specification,
            // and join them using comma and
            // newline. Done!
            System.out.println(
                columns.stream()
                       .map(col -> "  " + col.name +
                                    " " + col.type)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"))
            );

           System.out.println(");");
       }
   );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean SQL query generation happens till fetch() ? And later on afterwards stream() starts, everything is in memory inside java process

Yes

> Or are java 8 streams like active record DSL and whole snippet is converted into SQL queries including stream() part ?

No

> This is because I have seen examples where sortBy / groupingBy are being done inside streams in many online samples when they can be done in SQL as well

You probably mean the [JINQ library](http://www.jinq.org).

While jOOQ gives you access to the Java 8 `Stream` API (because every jOOQ result is, in fact, a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), and you can call [`List.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) on any list), it does not translate stream operations to SQL. While libraries like JINQ prove that this is possible, in principle, the `Stream` API offers *a lot* less functionality than the SQL language, which does not fit jOOQ's vision of giving users full SQL language access.